# How to select features from different WFS layers?

Tags: wfs, features, layers, select

I'm trying to select features from different WFS layers but unfortunatelly it doesn't works in my code.

**This is my code:**

```
var select = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Selection", {styleMap: new OpenLayers.Style(OpenLayers.Feature.Vector.style["select"])});
var hover = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Hover");

map.addLayers([hover,select]);

controles = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
        featureType: ["states","world"]}),
    box: true,
    hover: true,
    multipleKey: "shiftKey",
    toggleKey: "ctrlKey",
});

controles.events.register("featureselected", this, function(e) {
      select.addFeatures([e.feature]);
});

controles.events.register("featureunselected", this, function(e) {
      select.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
});

controles.events.register("hoverfeature", this, function(e) {
      hover.addFeatures([e.feature]);
});

controles.events.register("outfeature", this, function(e) {
      hover.removeFeatures([e.feature]);
});

map.addControl(controles);
controles.activate();
```

---

As you can see, I've put in the featureType two layers but only the first one can be selected. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

The documentation and source code say featureType has the type 'String' not array

```
controles = new OpenLayers.Control.GetFeature({
    protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
        url: "http://demo.opengeo.org/geoserver/wfs",
        featureType: "states"}),
    box: true,
    hover: true,
    multipleKey: "shiftKey",
    toggleKey: "ctrlKey",
});
```

It's better to create each layer in a single step and pass them to a OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature instance.

Here the link to the official example: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/select-feature-multilayer.html